# How can I sort a JTable by replacing all pre-existing values with the new sorted ones?

Tags: java, swing, sorting

I'm trying to make a GUI interface using java swing that is able to add users to a text file (I treat it as a database in which I pull/push to) and sort them. The GUI interface has a JTable which pulls the existing items in the text file and displays it initially. Once I go to add a new item, it gets updated. Now I'm trying to add a sorting functionality using bubble sort to sort the rows of JTable. I can't use something simple like the `TableRowSorter` which sorts the entire column if you click on it because I won't be able to track the changes and save them to the text file (my database). I need a way to almost replace all the values of the current JTable with a sorted one (the sorted one is called `arr`, it's the array I pass through the `BubbleSort` function) when I click on the button "Sort List" which then triggers the `actionPerformed` event. I'm struggling to find a way to do this and would appreciate some help.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.io.IOException;  // Import the IOException class to handle errors
import java.io.File;  // Import the File class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  // Import this class to handle errors
import java.nio.file.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

class UserManager extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  private JTextField firstNameField, lastNameField, salaryField;
  private JButton addButton, removeButton, viewButton, sortButton, getButton;
  private JList<Employee> userList;
  private ArrayList<Employee> users;
  private JTable j;
  private DefaultTableModel model;

  public UserManager() {
    setTitle("Employee Manager");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    firstNameField = new JTextField(20);
    lastNameField = new JTextField(20);
    salaryField = new JTextField(20);
    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.addActionListener(this);
    removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    removeButton.addActionListener(this);
    viewButton = new JButton("Refresh List");
    viewButton.addActionListener(this);
    sortButton = new JButton("Sort List");
    sortButton.addActionListener(this);

    // Pulling data from text file database
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> databaseData = ReadFile();

    users = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    // Adding existing databaseData to users
    try {
      if (databaseData.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < databaseData.size(); i++) {
          Employee user = new Employee(databaseData.get(i).get(0), databaseData.get(i).get(1), Integer.valueOf(databaseData.get(i).get(2)));
          users.add(user);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      
    }
    

    
    userList = new JList<Employee>(users.toArray(new Employee[0]));
    userList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


    JPanel firstNamePanel = new JPanel();
    firstNamePanel.add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
    firstNamePanel.add(firstNameField);

    JPanel lastNamePanel = new JPanel();
    lastNamePanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
    lastNamePanel.add(lastNameField);

    JPanel salaryPanel = new JPanel();
    salaryPanel.add(new JLabel("Salary:"));
    salaryPanel.add(salaryField);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(addButton);
    buttonPanel.add(removeButton);
    buttonPanel.add(sortButton);

    
    // Converting 2D arraylist to normal 2D array for JTable
    String[][] data = databaseData.stream().map(u -> u.toArray(new String[0])).toArray(String[][]::new);

    // Initializing column names of JTable
    String[] columnNames = { "FName", "LName", "Salary" };
    
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    j = new JTable(model);
    j.setBounds(1000, 1000, 900, 900);


    // adding it to JScrollPane
    JScrollPane table = new JScrollPane(j);
    
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 3));
    mainPanel.add(firstNamePanel);
    mainPanel.add(lastNamePanel);
    mainPanel.add(salaryPanel);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
    mainPanel.add(table);

    
    add(mainPanel);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    // Sort button is clicked
    else if (e.getSource() == sortButton) {
      // Checking if there's at least 2 items in the database
      if (users.size() > 1) {
        
        ArrayList<Employee> arr = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  
        // Creating a copy of users
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
          arr.add(users.get(i));
        }
  
        arr = BubbleSort(arr);
  
        updateList(arr);

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ----------------------------------------- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO SOMEHOW SORT THE JTABLE 
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ----------------------------------------- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      }
      else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Too Few Employees.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      }
    }
  }



  
  // Updates the list after a CRUD operation is called
  private void updateList(ArrayList<Employee> u) {
    userList.setListData(u.toArray(new Employee[0]));

    System.out.println("Updating Database");

    try {
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("db.txt", false);

      // Loop through each student and write to the text file
      for (int i = 0; i < u.size(); i++) {
        fw.write(toString(u.get(i).getFirstName(), u.get(i).getLastName(), u.get(i).getSalary()));
      }
      fw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException io) {}
  }





  
  // Combing multiple string and ints into a string
  public String toString(String firstName, String lastName, int salary) {
      return firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + salary + "\n";
  }


  
  // Method to read database
  public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ReadFile() {
    try {
      // Choose grades.txt file to look at
      File myObj = new File("db.txt");

      // Create scanner object
      Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);

      // Create 2d list array to hold all the single list arrays of single information
      ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> combinedArr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    
      // While the file reader is still reading lines in the text
      while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        // Read strings of text in txt file
        String data = myReader.nextLine();

        // Get first and last name from a string
        ArrayList<String> temp = GetName(data); 

        // Add the person and their salary to the combined array that holds everyones
        combinedArr.add(temp);
      }

      // Close file once there are no more lines to read
      myReader.close();

      return combinedArr;
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Return invalid list string with nothing if error
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Invalid = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    return Invalid;
  }

  // Method to perform bubble sort
  public static ArrayList<Employee> BubbleSort(ArrayList<Employee> arr) {
    // Looping through entire array's length - 1 times to avoid errors when comparing an index adn the next one
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) {
      // Looping through indexes
      for (int j = 0; j < arr.size() - 1; j++) {
        // If the current index element is bigger than next index element, swap them
        if (arr.get(j).getSalary() > arr.get(j+1).getSalary()) {
          Employee temp = arr.get(j);
          arr.set(j,arr.get(j+1));
          arr.set(j+1,temp);
        }
      }
    }

    return arr;
  }


  // Parses name in db
  public static ArrayList<String> GetName(String data) {
    String first = "";
    String last = "";
    String sal = "";
    // System.out.println(data[0])
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
      if (data.charAt(i) == ',') {
        // Start from 2 indexes after the first occurance of the comma
        for (int j = i+2; j < data.length(); j++) {
          if (data.charAt(j) == ',') {
            for (int n = j+2; n < data.length(); n++) {
              sal += data.charAt(n);
            }
            break;
          }
          last += data.charAt(j);
        }
        break;
      }
      first += data.charAt(i);
    }

    // Initializing package array to send all values
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr.add(first);
    arr.add(last);
    arr.add(sal);
    
    return arr;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      UserManager frame = new UserManager();
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}



class Employee {
  // Initalizing variables
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private int salary;

  // Assigning variables
  public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int salary) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.salary = salary;
  }

  // return first name
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  // return last name
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  // return salary
  public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is it important that you have the records stored in sorted order? Why not just maintain the records as is and present them in a sorted manner? Why are you implementing your own (slower) sorting algorithm and not making use of the pre-existing sorting capabilites of something like [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))?

Comment: Hint - create a new `TableModel` with the sorted data and set it to the `JTable`

Comment: Pull the data from database table(s) in the sort order you want with your SQL Query.

Answer (score -1):

First step is to sort all of the data you want inside of the JTable as you want it, and then create a 2 dimensional array of type `Object` that contains your sorted data, with each object inside being a row.

After that you should add a new `TableModel` to your JTable using the `setModel(TableModel)` method inside of `JTable`:

```
j.setModel(new AbstractModel(){
    public int getRowCount(){
        return sortedDataInA2DArray.length;
    }

   public int getColumnCount(){
       return numOfColumns;
   }

   public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
       return sortedDataInA2DArray[rowIndex][columnIndex];
   }
});
```

(I used `AbstractModel` in this demonstration as it is a lot easier to use than `TableModel`, but if you wanted to pass a `TableModel` interface into `setModel` you could, you'd just have to implement every method inside of `TableModel` interface)

Of course, `sortedDataInA2DArray` is the sorted 2d array of data you created.